# I continuously receive this error whenever a button is pressed to go to another view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, button, icloud

In my application I have a button that when pressed takes the user to a Navigation Controller that has a table view which contains eta that is aged in iCloud. The problem is that whenever the user presses this button there is an error that is described as...

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

I am not quite sure what this is trying to tell me about the command. So what is the best solution that I can use to try to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the console log instead? And the code you use on your IBAction?

Comment: That isn't actually the error. That's basically the initial launch code for your application, so you're probably looking at the stack trace instead.

Comment: You need to post the console log

Comment: You should post the error that is output to the console in Xcode (what you have posted is your App's `main` function).

Comment: See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Answer (score 0):

Probably in some storyboard or nib the button is callin an action that is not implementef in the viewcontroller. Create an exception breakpoint to have the debugger stop at the actual cause of the crash instead of at main.